# What does "status -12" mean in Android AudioTrack?

Tags: android, soundpool, audioflinger

When using Android soundpool/audioTrack, I keep getting the following error:

```
AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
Error creating AudioTrack
```

Can anyone explain what `-12` is? Is it the value of some enum from the source code?

I've seen other questions that deal with error `-12` but nowhere conclusively do I see what that constant actually stands for. Does someone know the list of the possible statuses for AudioFlinger? I've also seen error `-22` around, but I don't know what that means either.

Answers backed up by source code or documentation would be best, but I'll take any information I can get at this point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AudioFlinger could not create track. status: -12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964623/audioflinger-could-not-create-track-status-12)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
-12 is ENOMEM Not enough space

-22 is EINVAL Invalid argument.
```

These are standard POSIX error codes

Answer (score 8):

-12 means that you can not create a track anymore. Android Audio Framework allows only 32 tracks(includes playing/stopped/paused/...) per mixer thread at the same time.

try to remove some apps on background, you can create one.