# Shutter noises stop

Tags: android, noise, audioflinger, shutter

After about 10-15 photos, the shutter noise stops working and doesn't come back until you restart the app. This error is in android studio:

```
02-10 10:20:03.626 491-13501/? E/AudioFlinger: no more track names 
available 02-10 10:20:03.626 491-13501/? E/AudioFlinger: 
createTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block? 02-10 
10:20:03.626 31837-31837/ E/AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create 
track, status: -12 02-10 10:20:03.627 31837-31837/ E/SoundPool: Error 
creating AudioTrack
```

Here is the code:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MediaActionSound sound = new MediaActionSound();
        sound.play(MediaActionSound.SHUTTER_CLICK);
    }
}
```

Comment: can u please provide the full code snippet

Comment: Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {



                    MediaActionSound sound = new MediaActionSound();
                    sound.play(MediaActionSound.SHUTTER_CLICK);
  }

            });


            myThread.start();

Comment: you are opening multiple objects without calling release..see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964623/audioflinger-could-not-create-track-status-12

Answer (score 1):

In my application I use this code. I also had a similar problem (the sound was not played to the end after several playing). But after reusing (instead of re-creating) MediaActionSound problem has gone.

PS: sound play asynchronously, so you don't need to create a thread.

```
static private MediaActionSound sound = null;

static public void playShutterSound(){
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        if(sound == null) {
            sound = new MediaActionSound();
        }
        sound.play(MediaActionSound.SHUTTER_CLICK);
    }
}
```